# Rails group_by with increasing sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the User model in my application. They belong_to a Season model. I want to generate a chart with the evolution of the User registrations from a Season. For example:

```
u = Season.first
u.users #results in:
[#< User id: 1, created_at: some date, #< User id 2, created_at: some other date ]
```

I am using the gem groupdate to get the ammount of users created by month and it works like this:

```
 u.users.group_by_month("users.created_at").count
```

and this line results something like this:

```
{Wed, 01 Jul 2015 00:00:00 BRT -03:00=>2, Sat, 01 Aug 2015 00:00:00 BRT -03:00=>0, Tue, 01 Sep 2015 00:00:00 BRT -03:00=>0, Thu, 01 Oct 2015 00:00:00 BRT -03:00=>0, Sun, 01 Nov 2015 00:00:00 BRST -02:00=>3}
```

So, it returns the ammount of new users per month. Great!

Now I want to get the total ammount of users registered by that month. So if the first month had one user and the second I had 3 more, it would show [1,4] instead of [1,3]. I want to get the evolution of registered users. So for the current month it would result the total ammount of registered users.

After the inject suggestion by @jvnill, I ended up with:

```
u.users.group_by_month("users.created_at").count.inject({}) do 
   |cumulative, (date, total)|
   cumulative[date] = total + (cumulative.values.last || 0)
   cumulative
end
```

But that sound a bit hacky. Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you already have the list of counts for each month in a hash where the keys are the months and the values are the totals for each month, you can just iterate over the hash and save the cumulative total in an array.  I am not sure if there is a shortcut for this in the core Array methods.

```
counts = u.users.group_by_month('users.created_at').count

counts.inject(0) do |sum, (date, total)|
  counts[date] = sum + total
end

p counts
```

Comment: But this would result in something like [0,2,4,7,9] but I want {date1 => 3, date2 => 5, date3 => 7... and so on } could inject do that as well? @jvnill

Comment: updated the answer.  It may be a little cleaner but I'm not sure there's a shortcut.